# enable form when another row edit click

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jsp

I have the form disabled when click edit form is enable

```
<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
<form method='POST' action='EditCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>'>
<tbody>
    <tr align='center'>
        <td><%= no %></td>
        <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(2)%>' name='company_name'></td>  
        <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(3)%>' name='city'></td>  
        <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(4)%>' name='state'></td> 
        <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(5)%>' name='zipcode'></td>   
        <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(6)%>' name='branch'></td>    
        <td><input class="form-control aaa" type="text" disabled="disabled" value='<%= resultset.getString(7)%>' name='address'></td>
        <td><a class='abc' id='elementId' onclick="showDiv()"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a> <input type='submit' class="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;"></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-href="DeleteCompany?id=<%= resultset.getString(1)%>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </form>
    <% no++; } %>
```

This is the Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.abc').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled',false);
});</script>
```

This is fact

[image]

But I want like this. When I want to cancel to edit row 1 and I want to edit row 2, I want the row 1 disabled like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.abc').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('tr').parent().find('.aaa').prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.aaa').prop('disabled', false);
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.abc').click(function(){
    $('tr .aaa').prop('disabled',false);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').prop('disabled',true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Code dump answer from a ~7k user? For shame. Explain yourself!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like,

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings("tr").find('.aaa').attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.aaa').attr('disabled', false);
});
```